# The derivative of a family of flows

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

If one has a family of flows, can one describe the derivative in the "family" direction?

Specifically, let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let
  $X_{s,t}$
be a 2-parameter family of fields on $M$. That is, it's a map
$$
\mathbb{R}^2 \to \Gamma(TM),
\qquad
(s,t) \mapsto X_{s,t}.
$$
This generates a 2-parameter family $\Phi_{s,t}$ of diffeomorphisms of $M$, but not uniquely. Let's choose one as follows:
$$
\Phi_{s,t}(x) = 
\text{the time $t$ flow of the $t$-dependent vector field $X_s(t)$}.
$$

So we have a map
$$
\Phi: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times M \to M,
\qquad
(s,t,x) \mapsto \Phi_{s,t}(x).
$$

> Question: Is there a concrete way to write down the $s$ component of the derivative of $\Phi$? That is, is there a formula for $D \Phi(\partial_s)$ in terms of $X$?

For instance, by definition, the $t$ component of the derivative is simply
$$
D\Phi|_{x,s,t}(\partial_t) = X_s(t).
$$

Some remarks:

1. To be explicit, the map $\Phi$ is as follows: For each $s$, consider the $t$-family of vector fields $X_s(t)$. One can flow the manifold along this $t$-family, and the image of $x$ at time $t$ is $\Phi_{s,t}(x)$. 
   (An inequivalent map would send $x$ to the time $s$ flow of the $s$-dependent vector field $X_t(s)$.)
2. I believe $\Phi$ is smooth if one assumes that $X_{s,t}$ is smooth in both $s$ and $t$. (I don't know if the proof of the existence of solutions to ODEs guarantees regularity of families of flows.)
3. This is probably either (a) a simple exercise with answers in terms of Lie derivatives and connections, or (b) unreasonable to ask. Regardless I haven't been able to write down any useful answer.
4. Note there's a non-trivial $t$ dependence on $D\Phi(\partial_s)$. One can see this because at $t=0$, $D\Phi(\partial_s) = 0$, while for $t \neq 0$, the derivative is not zero on $\partial_s$.

I haven't tried writing anything in terms of connections, as I didn't want to impose any metrics on the situation--clearly the answer is independent of any such choices--but I will certainly accept answers that impose a metric and write the answer in terms of the Levi-Civita connection.

Here are some motivating examples:

1. $f_s: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a family of Morse functions, and you're curious how their time $t$ Morse flows are related. (Here, $\nabla f$ has no $t$-dependance.)
2. Let $M$ be symplectic, and assume $H_{s,t}: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a family of $t$-dependent Hamiltonians on $M$. Then one is interested in how the Hamiltonian flows of $H_{s,t}$ are related as one varies $s$.